# Sharepoint 2010 GlobalNavigation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation

I have a request for a client who has three level of navigation and would like to use the global navigation to set the navigation links in site site settings>navigation.(/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)

Is that doable?

Thanks in advance for your reply :)
Will

- 1st level navigation

  - 2nd level navigation

    - 3rd level navigation

so for the navigation we would have something like that:

- Company (1st level navigation)

  - About us (2nd level navigation)

    - Contact us (3rd level navigation)
    - Team (3rd level navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good tutorial http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-two-tier-global.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

[image]

Comment: that sounds like it could work for a custom navigation but in my case my client need to be able to change the navigation from Site Settings : Navigation Settings (_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)

Comment: I would suggest you to create global menu using XSLT and custom list. Create two seprate custom list 1- Head Menu and 2- Menu. Draw your xslt for dyamaic menus by these lists and place this xslt on pleace of flobal navigation. Your client can set menus by entry in 'Head Menu' and 'Menu' custom lists