# Is it possible to change the location of Global navigation in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to change the location of Global navigation in Sharepoint 2010?

Change it from Top link to title and navigation bar.

Comment: May be this will be helpful to ypu

try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365065/sharepoint-2010-globalnavigation

Comment: You can try to use custom master page.